# Using Index function without exact matches

Tags: list, function, indexing, wildcard, excel-2013

I don't know the easiest way to get this done. I have 1 list of account names given to me, and a list of over 15,000 account names with corresponding sales rep names from our system. I need to know if the accounts on my list have assigned sales reps and who they are.

The way I have it set up is

Column A: System List

Column B: Corresponding sales rep

Column C: My account list

Column D: =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))

This produces some correct results but some of the account names aren't exact which causes a problem. For example

Column A: American Services Inc

Column C: American Services

Column D: #N/A

I'm stuck on what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific example presented you can do this wildcard match:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2&"*",A:A,0))
```

But depending on how "different" the entries in your lists are that should match, you may need an heuristics [fuzzy-match add-in](https://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/microsoft-fuzzy-lookup-add-in-for-excel-2010-walkthrough/).